# Returning aggregated values as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that has been grouped on two columns, and a custom function that computes a tuple of values from each grouped set of rows. 
I am trying to collect the results in a dataframe, indexed with the original group indexes. When I use `apply()` I get a `Series` with the correct indices, but with the values in the form of tuples. How should I write my function in order for the result to be a dataframe, indexed by the labels for each group?

Here's an example based on the dataframe in the tutorial.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                          'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : 1,
                   'D' : range(0, 8) })
groups = df.groupby(("A", "B"))

def myfunc(grp):
    return len(grp), sum(grp["D"])

result = groups.apply(myfunc)

print(type(result))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
A    B    
bar  one       (1, 4)
     three     (1, 8)
     two      (1, 12)
foo  one      (2, 16)
     three    (1, 16)
     two      (2, 16)
```

I would like the result to be a dataframe, e.g. with columns named "size" and "sum". What should my aggregating function look like, and what else do I need to do to access the individual labels (columns `A` and `B`) for each row of the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aggregating function needs to return a pandas Series. In this case, the overall groupby-apply will result in a pandas DataFrame:

```
def myfunc(grp):
    return pd.Series({"size": len(grp), "sum": sum(grp["D"])})
```

Using a dictionary here automatically labels your final result data frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
def myfunc(grp):
    return pd.Series([len(grp), sum(grp["D"])])
```

Try returning Series

Comment: Thank you, constructing a Series was the missing ingredient. I upvoted you both, but I accepted @pansen's answer since it includes more features.